# How to perform multistep initialization of val

Tags: kotlin

In order learn a bit of `kotlin` I am building a parser combinator library based loosely on the classic paper [Monadic Parser Combinators](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monparsing.pdf)
.

In my case I need to forward declare a parser because of recursive syntax. When preparing the final expression parser I need to update the forward declaration

My first attempt was this

```
val addLike             = mulLike separatedBy addLikeSeparator
val expression          = 
  forwarded.second(addLike)
  addLike
```

The idea is to perform a short initalization then return `addLike` to initialize the value. This is a very common pattern when I do some F# programming and I think it's a good pattern because it simplifies hiding initialization details.

This doesn't work in `kotlin` however:

```
Error:(195, 5) Kotlin: Expecting a top level declaration
```

This approach also fails:

```
val addLike             = mulLike separatedBy addLikeSeparator
val expression          = forwarded.second(addLike); addLike
```

The problem seem to be that `;` combines two `expressions` into a `statement`.

So I tried `,` in the hope that it behaves somewhat like C/C++ but no luck:

```
val addLike             = mulLike separatedBy addLikeSeparator
val expression          = forwarded.second(addLike), addLike
```

After reading the `kotlin` specification I found no clear solutions so that's why I turned to StackOverflow. Can this pattern be implemented in an idiomatic way in `kotlin`?

**Update**

@Eric suggested the use if `run` and if I update my code with that the final solution ends up a bit like this:

```
val expression          = run () {
                                forwarded.second(addLike)
                                whitespaces keepRight addLike keepLeft expectEOS()
                          }
```

That it is acceptable to me. Thanks @Eric.

Comment: your intend is kind of unclear without knowing F# :( 
What are you trying to do in terms of data/values/operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to execute initialization code on an object before assigning it to any data field.

You can use the [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) function. with [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) you can write a lambda function where you can perform your initialization code then assign the returned value of the lambda as the value of the data field:

```
val expression = run()
{
    // initialization code here
    forwarded.second(addLike)

    // writing "return@run" is optional
    return@run addLike
}
```

you can also use [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) as mentioned in [Alexander Udalov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008720/2898715). you can instantiate the value you would like to assign the data field to and have the initialization code in the lambda passed into [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html):

```
val expression = addLike.apply()
{
    // initialization code here
    forwarded.second(this) // "this" refers to addLike within this lambda
}
```

you can use the [lazy delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy). this is similar to run, except the lambda won't execute right away during construction to initialize the data field. instead, it will be executed the first time the data field is accessed:

```
val expression by lazy()
{
    // initialization code here
    forwarded.second(addLike)

    // writing "return@run" is optional
    return@lazy addLike
}
```

oh, and then there's also `init`. you can actually have multiple `init` blocks in one class, and they'll be executed in order that they appear in the file (top to bottom)

```
val addLike: SomeType
val expression: AnotherType

init {
    addLike = mulLike separatedBy addLikeSeparator
    forwarded.second(addLike)
    expression = addLike
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the different suggestions. In my case I prefer `run`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) function from the standard library. It performs an operation on its receiver and then returns it:

```
val expression = addLike.apply { forwarded.second(this) }
```

Comment: To clarify, the "it" that is returned is the receiver, not the operation :)